# Inductive Cholesky decomposition to prove that a function is positive definite over the natural numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove that the function:

$$k(a,b):=\frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} \right )}$$

is a positive definite function over the natural numbers. What has sometimes proven useful in these cases is inductive Cholesky decomposition to find an embedding $\phi(n)$ for each number $n$:

Equation 1):
$$\phi(n+1) = \left(\begin{array}{r}
{C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \\
\sqrt{k(n+1,n+1)-{\left| {C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \right|}^{2} }
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 2):

$$v_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
k(1,n+1) \\
k(2,n+1) \\
\cdots\\
k(n,n+1)\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 3):
$$C_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
\phi(1)^T \\
\phi(2)^T \\
\cdots\\
\phi(n)^T\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 4):
$$\phi(1) := \sqrt{k(1,1)} e_1$$

If we assume that the function $k$ is positive definite, then this inductive method, should give us the vectors $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ such that under the normal inner product we have:

$$k(a,b) = \left < \phi(a), \phi(b) \right > $$

and this will give us a possibility to look at the features/entries of this vector and define $\phi(a)$ this way, thereby proving that $k(a,b)$ is positive definite.

Usually, when trying to apply this method to wild speculated functions, such as functions associated with the ABC-conjecture as for example:

$$\frac{2(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b) \operatorname{rad}(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3})^2}$$

the method will work, but the coefficients produced by this method grow very fast and there is no chance in trying to guess a pattern for such a beast.

But for the function mentioned in the beginning there seems to be a pattern for the numbers $1-11$:

$$
\left(1\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{3}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{3},\,0,\,\frac{2}{3} \, \sqrt{2}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{3},\,0,\,\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{5},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\frac{2}{5} \, \sqrt{6}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{6},\,\frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{3},\,\frac{1}{3} \, \sqrt{2},\,0,\,0,\,\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{7},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\frac{4}{7} \, \sqrt{3}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{3},\,0,\,\frac{1}{4} \, \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{3},\,0,\,\frac{1}{6} \, \sqrt{2},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{10},\,\frac{1}{10} \, \sqrt{3},\,0,\,0,\,\frac{1}{5} \, \sqrt{6},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\frac{3}{5} \, \sqrt{2}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{11},\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\frac{2}{11} \, \sqrt{30}\right)
$$

Looking carefully one observes the pattern:

$$\psi(n) = \sum_{d|n} \sqrt{x_{n,d}} e_d $$

for some rational number $x_{n,d}$.

Question: Can this be proven or the positive definiteness of $k$?

[Here is the Sagemath implementation of the inductive Cholesky decomposition.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UstuwyAQvFfKPyD1As6rdm9Vc8pnWFGFDUlWMY8CsdO_L9ghxklaELaBndnZWb-i-qgabk8_iPFaCa0sOFBy9hIm43tkKMOSfMxekB-Gu7ORSBvFsDYg-BeDFqwy1seQEXQ6Ybqo7lBFhum8IutDzfrbLF8HcppV9xfZu1_Fv2Q3bIIqyBAywLQGTB-ETzTTCUCI8wPAngUuG3XAmqC9MkgjkFfm3QTMwLonMu23cXggnodXRZZFFj6iakJQMib6jzAaD3skN5v8uksStLx2yuAyj3J4Y3kS1qEN2m6xXObeIByebdvvxpAmxDRBfzc5XVGtuWS4r8E3Qc7zhV9k2a2kMgL3jpO_FDUdiQ0MGe98ibI9LfSkvbsQ3DVUHjgeUo0ej76EaiKbEF56uRs2TxkSK1qIdQZrIZXu7W24xC0Q9IlkghlwK35xwQlvHJCsfNslUCGiTx49qVFQZ-Diu38rIsygUqYq8yKK9H-ndFguhs6TX06a7r0=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number $n=\prod_ip_i^{\beta_i}$ say that $n\parallel a$ if $p_i^{\beta_i}\parallel a$ for all $i$. Denote by $\gcd'(a,b)$ the largest $n$ such that $n\parallel a$ and $n\parallel b$.

$\def\rad{\mathop{\mathrm{rad}}\nolimits}$Notice that
$$
  k(a,b)=\frac{f(a,b)}{\rad(a)\rad(b)},
$$
where
$$
  f(a,b)=\rad(\gcd(a,b))\cdot \rad(\gcd'(a,b)).
$$
The factors $\rad(a)$ and $\rad(b)$ cen be ruled out by a linear change. So we need to show that $f(a,b)$ is positive definite. For that purpose, we represent $f$ as a sum of many positive semidefinite functions $f_\alpha$.

A sufficient condition for $f_\alpha$ to satisfy the goal is that $f_\alpha(a,b)=c_\alpha \mathbf 1_{X_\alpha}(a)\mathbb 1_{X_\alpha}(b)$ for some set $X_\alpha$ and some $c_\alpha>0$.

Let $D$ be the set of products of different primes, i.e., of numbers $d$ satisfying $d=\rad(d)$. For $d\in D$, set
$$  
  g_{d}(a,b)=\varphi(d)\mathbf 1_{d\mid a}\mathbf 1_{d\mid b}.
$$
Then
$$
  \sum_d g_{d}(a,b)=\rad(\gcd(a,b)).
$$

Similarly, for ecvery positive integer $n$ denote
$$
  h_n(a,b)=\varphi(\rad(n))\cdot \mathbf 1_{n\parallel a}\mathbf 1_{n\parallel b}.
$$
Then
$$
  \rad(\gcd'(a,b))=\sum_n h_n(a,b).
$$

Therefore, the functions $f_{d,n}(a,b)=g_d(a,b)h_n(a,b)$ fir the goal.
Hence $f$ is positive semidefinite.

It is now an easy exercise to show that in fact it is positive definite: if you take the vectos whose last nonzero coordinate has number $n$, then the quadratic form given by $f_{\rad(n),n}$ takes a strictly positive value on that vector.